# Automating Time-Based Actions in a .NET Web API Application and SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In my .NET Web API application that contains an `Auctions` table with an `EndTime` property (`DateTime` datatype), once the auction has expired (`EndTime == DateTime.Now`), I want to automatically select the winning bid from the `Bids` table and do some actions (process payment, send email, etc).

What would be the best way of doing this? I have taught about creating background jobs to execute once every 60 seconds to check but that doesn't seem very optimized or best practice.

I have also learned about creating a stored procedure in SQL Server that checks the auctions every 60 seconds and if the datetime value is now then execute a helper application that calls the API.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

I haven't tried anything as I do not know where to start.

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism in mssql to notify that a datetime field surpasses a threshold. You will have to poll for the event to occur.  In your case, the polling performs a simple comparison of two datetimes, therefore, I would imagine that the polling interval of whatever mechanism used could be tightened up to a smaller value than every 60 seconds.

Comment: Take a look at BackgroundService https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services or HangFire library. https://www.hangfire.io/ Write your own code, and ask the questions if you get stuck after you did some troubleshooting. The way the question is written, it is not appropriate for Stack Overflow

Comment: you can schedule a task in EndTime - DateTime.Now seconds that sets the winning bid. If new bids reverse the countdown, you can save the cancellationtoken or whatever it's called these days in .net and use it to cancel and reschedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `Hangfire` library to schedule a task when the object is created. Simple to setup and use.

Comment: SQL Server already has SQL Server Agent for scheduled jobs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).